# How do I turn on Samsung LS24D332HSX/ZA 24" FHD

Tags: display

I’ve just bought this monitor brand new, Samsung LS24D332HSX/ZA 24" FHD Monitor Black" and it will not turn on. I’ve plugged in the power and video cable, I’m wondering if there is a power switch I just can’t find because online the other models seem to have a power switch or a jog switch while mine seems to have neither.

Answer (score 0):

From your product manual ([available on the Samsung website](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/flat/24-sd332-fast-response-fhd-monitor-ls24d332hsx-za/)) you should have a set of capacitive buttons in the bottom corner of your monitor. The look like text or overlay print, but they are actually buttons.

[image]

Comment: The buttons on the front do not do anything I’m pretty sure they just sent me a faulty monitor